# Zend framework - db_table - wrong datatype being saved

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db-table

I'm using the Zend_db_table insert() method and get an error. The error is because I receiving data from POST as a string but the datatype for the table column is float. So it creates error when I try to insert string type into float column.

What's the proper way to resolve this?

Here's the model code:

```
class User_Model_Forms extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
    public function save(array $data) {
        return $this->insert($data);
    }
    ...
```

Here's the controller code:

```
$form = new User_Form_Firstpart();
if ( $form->isValid($request->getPost()) ){
    $data = $form->getValues();
    $formModel = new User_Model_Forms();
    $formModel->save($data);

    ...
```

Here's the database table:

[image: form table]

Comment: Could you paste some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the input to float before passing it to insert:

```
$this->insert(array(
    'someColumn' => (float) $the_value,
));
```

BTW don't forget to add a float validator to your form.